# Hotkey for placing two windows

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window-manager

Oftentimes it is desirable to let two windows each consume exactly half of the screen. I want to do this with emacs and the terminal so that I can look up C documentation while coding.

How could I make my system such that when emacs is opened from terminal, then the terminal and emacs will reposition themselves appropriately to the two halves of my screen? Or is there a better solution for my intended purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcuts <kbd>ctrl-alt</kbd> and numpad numbers will position windows.

<kbd>ctrl-alt-4</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl-alt-6</kbd> will cover the left and right half of the screen, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether there is a keyboard shortcut for that, but as an alternative you could use a tiling window manager like [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/), [wmii](http://wmii.suckless.org/) or the likes. However this may be overkill if you would just like to position these two windows correctly. Although if you would like to have the tiling behaviour deeply embedded into your window manager those are two choices I would go after.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Adrian's keyboard shortcut answer, the mouse can also be used to achieve the same effect by dragging a window to the left or right hand edge of the screen and it will grow to use one-half of the screen.